# how to call a child class inside its parent class?

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Society
{
void add_student(string name,string home_town)//add student to society
{
    Student a;
a.set_name(name);
a.set_home_town(home_town);
}
bool same_community(Student s1, Student s2){}//check if student 1 & student 2 are in the same community
void join_communities(Student s1,Student s2){}//join communities which student 1 & student 2 are in
int num_of_communities(){}//return the total number of communities inside the society
float max_diversity(){}//return the highest diversity between all communities 
};

class Community : public Society
{
void add(Student new_student){}//add new student to community
bool contains(string name_student){}//whether community contains a student named name_student
void join(Community other_community){}//add all students in other_community to this community
float diversity(){}//return the number of distinct hometowns/names for this community
};

class Student :public Community
{
string name, string home_town;
public:
void set_name(string a){name=a;}
void set_home_town(string b){home_town=b;}
string get_name() const{return name;}
string get_home_town() const{return home_town;}
};
```

I have a parent class named Society and I would like to use its child class named Student in some of the functions.how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you not indent your code?

Comment: Base classes should not know about classes that derive from them. Ever. Look up [the visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) instead.

Comment: By the way, in what way is a Student a kind of Community? Your inheritance tree seems broken.

Comment: it states in my exercise that a student should be taken az a one man community

Comment: I encourage you to read about the "is-a" relationship for public inheritance. "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers is a good place to start.

Comment: @aminKaramlou you might want to ask for clarifications about the "a student is a one man community" part. As mentionned by Chris A., it would look much more likely that a society "has" a number of student (potentially one), rather than a student "be" a kind of society. (Unless there is some sort of interface puzzle). Gook luck if your teachers are not clear enough on that...

Comment: Well, that's somewhat ridiculous!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other comments, but if necessary, you can apply [CRTP pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) with this form. However, this solution only apply to Student communities, you can't mix different community members:

```
template<typename T>
class Society
{
    void add_student(string name,string home_town)
    {
        T student;
        student.set_name(name);
        ......
    }
    ....
};

template <typename T>
class Comunity : public Society<T>
{
    void add(T new_student){}//add new student to community
    ....
};

class Student : public Comunity<Student>
{
    .....
}
```